# Difference between unbracketed v. bracketed 'for loop' in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am very confused on why the following two for-loop scenarios generate different outputs, starting from the same list of lines:

```
 print lines
   ['175.11\n', '176.39\t56.887\n', '178.17\n', '176.1\t51.679\n', '176.1\t51.679\n', '175.15\n', '176.91\t32.149\t30.344\n', '182.33\n', '173.04\n', '174.31\n']
```

**SCENARIO #1: Bracketed for-loop**

When I run the following:

```
lines = ["Total = "+line for line in lines]
print lines
```

lines becomes:

```
['Total = 175.11\n', 'Total = 176.39\t56.887\n', 'Total = 178.17\n', 'Total = 176.1\t51.679\n', 'Total = 176.1\t51.679\n', 'Total = 175.15\n', 'Total = 176.91\t32.149\t30.344\n', 'Total = 182.33\n', 'Total = 173.04\n', 'Total = 174.31\n']
```

**SCENARIO #2: Un-bracketed for-loop**

But, when I run this:

```
for line in lines:
    lines = ["Total = "+line]
print lines
```

lines becomes only:

```
['Total = 174.31\n']
```

I would greatly appreciate any help explaining what's going on here! (Also, I should mention that I am more interested in the output from SCENARIO #1, but would like to accomplish it using the format of SCENARIO #2).

Comment: Have you read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/tutorial)?  What you are calling a "bracketed for loop" is in fact a list comprehension, which is not a for loop at all (although it has some similarities).

Comment: Ahh OK, thank you @BrenBarn! I didn't realize that...I didn't know how else to google "for loop in brackets". That explains a lot now.

Answer (score 3):

**You are overwriting your list of each loop iteration**, as opposed to appending to it.

The fix would be:

```
myList = []
for line in lines:
    myList.append("Total = " + line) # appends the r-value to your list
```

But I still prefer list comprehension for its conciseness, anyway.

You can also use condition list comprehension:

```
# excludes empty lines
myList = ["Total = "+line for line in lines if len(line) > 0]
```

**You are modifying a list that you are iterating through**

As your for loop progresses through your `lines` you are appending new items. Any time you modify a container you are iterating through the results can be damaging. [Read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python).

Comment: Isn't `list` a builtin in Python?

Comment: @PeterWood my mistake. Edited to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, `list` is the name for the builtin list type.

Comment: `list` is indeed a built-in, which you can easily check.

Comment: Er... no, [**`list`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?#list) is a type.

Comment: Hmm, I tried the first fix but I think python is having trouble leaving the loop because it's not finishing the script...or perhaps something else is happening. (Edit: I used "lines2" instead of "list")

Comment: @Dennis I'll update answer to cover that, one moment.

Comment: And why are you doing an augmented list assignment instead of just using `append`?

Comment: @AidanGomez Actually, this all worked wonderfully. I had  a typo, and now it works great. Thank you!

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I was mimicking his formatting. I agree that append is more clear and concise.

Comment: @Dennis glad it worked! Accept the answer at your convenience.

Comment: `if len(line) > 0` can also be replaced with `if line`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I believe SO has post editing functionality. However, I'm at issue with the modification because the sacrifice of clarity is too great. Especially in an already pseudo-unclear functionality like list comprehension.

Comment: The use of truthy and falsey values is a basic feature of Python that results in cleaner, more concise code. Avoiding it is the equivalent of using `if myval == False: return False; else: return True` rather than `return myval`.